# How to get short month name from time.Now() in Golang

Tags: go, time

```golang
current := time.Now().UTC()
y, m, d := current.Date()
fmt.Println(y, m, d)
```

Output:

```
2009 November 10
```

How can I get short month name? Like:

```
2009 Nov 10
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [Format](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) function with `Jan` for short month name, ie

```
current := time.Now().UTC()
fmt.Println(current.Format("2006 Jan 02"))
```

Comment: you need to pass that exact string to Forma, because the time package's reference time is "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006"

Comment: If I need only month name, then I need to split it again. Thats why I actually think `m.String()[:3]` this one is less expensive.. up voted

Comment: @AerofoilKite If you only need (short) month name then use format string which only returns it, ie `fmt.Println(current.Format("Jan"))`, no need to split anything!

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for this solution.

Comment: How do I return the same response in a specific language?

Comment: Unfortunately Go doesn't support this out of the box, maybe some thirdparty lib can do it.

Answer (score 5):

Use `time.Now().UTC().Format("Jan")` or `m.String()[:3]` to get short month name:

```golang
current := time.Now().UTC()
y, m, d := current.Date()
fmt.Println(y, m.String()[:3], d)
```

Also you may use `fmt.Sprintf("%d %s %02d", t.Year(), t.Month().String()[:3], t.Day())`
like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().UTC().Format("Jan")) // Aug

    t := time.Now()
    str := fmt.Sprintf("%d %s %02d", t.Year(), t.Month().String()[:3], t.Day())
    fmt.Println(str) // 2016 Aug 03
}
```

output:

```
Aug 
2016 Aug 03
```

Comment: You are right... I want to use this.. I need only short month name.